# JS works fine in Chrome but not in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

It's a simple window scroll that triggers when the user clicks on a nav item but for the life of me I cant seem to figure out why FF wont recognise it, I've read a similar Q&A's but they only recommend defining var's first which I've done, any help would be appreciated.

Heres the code:

```
$("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(){
var hash = this.hash;

//make sure this.hash has a value
if (hash !== ""){
    //prevent default anchor click behavior
    event.preventDefault();


    //use jQuerys animate() method to add smooth scroll
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, function(){

        window.location.hash = hash;
    });
} // end of if
});
```

Comment: event is not declared on that scope, maybe you are missing $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event){

Comment: Did you try to wrap `$( document ).ready()` around your event handler? [jQuery.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thank you @juvian that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

This "works" in Chrome because Chrome implements the non-standard [Window.event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) property.

As noted in the comments, you should use the `event` argument that is provided by jQuery event handler instead.

```
$("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event){
    ...
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```